# Why is openssl complaining that my certificate chain is self-signed?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, openssl

I am trying to set up a certificate chain for a lab server.  I have created my own root CA, an intermediate CA and a server certificate.  I supplied these certificates along with the server key to the openssl s_server command.  When I run openssl s_client and connect to that server, openssl complains that there is a self-signed certificate in the chain.

When I connect to a public web server using s_client, however, not only does the server not send all of the certificates in the chain (just the intermediate parent certificate of the server certificate) but openssl doesn't complain about a self-signed certificate, let alone an incomplete certificate chain.

If I use s_server with a CA file containing just the server's parent intermediate certificate, s_client complains that it can't get the local issuer certificate.  I never see this error with public web servers even though they don't send the entire certificate chain.

In none of these tests (using my own certificates or public web servers) I am using the -CApath, -CAfile or -verify options with the s_client command.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  Why does s_client complain about my certificate chain even though I don't use -verify?  Why is it complaining about my (I assume) root certificate being self-signed when all root certificates are self-signed?

For example, this is what I get with a public web server:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername security.stackexchange.com -connect security.stackexchange.com:443
CONNECTED(00000004)
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.stackexchange.com
verify return:1
---
```

But using s_server with my full certificate chain, I get this:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername server.domain.com -connect server.domain.com:443
CONNECTED(00000004)
depth=2 C = US, ST = State, L = City, O = Company, OU = Company CA
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
---
```

Here are my certificates.  And yes, I have the constraints CA=TRUE, Digital Signature and Certificate Sign set in my root CA.

```
openssl x509 -in root_ca.cert.pem -noout -text
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            bc:e0:9f:2a:5d:25:6e:8f
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=State, L=City, O=Company, OU=Company CA
        Validity
            Not Before: May 30 22:35:50 2019 GMT
            Not After : May 25 22:35:50 2039 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=State, L=City, O=Company, OU=Company CA
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
.........
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                2A:0A:D6:EF:96:02:70:4F:89:7A:69:C5:3E:37:47:EE:B1:E1:92:C0
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:2A:0A:D6:EF:96:02:70:4F:89:7A:69:C5:3E:37:47:EE:B1:E1:92:C0

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
.........
```

root CA:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

intermediate CA:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

server certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: s_client does verify the cert chain using default roots installed by your distro. By default it doesn't stop after verification failed because it's a test tool, but it does verify. If you specify -CAfile, does it work? The complaint about self-signed is because the domain's cert is issued by something not trusted by the trusted roots, not because the root itself is self-signed (as you noted, all roots are self-signed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, it is quite correct for a TLS/SSL server to send the intermediate aka chain cert(s) but not the root cert; see [rfc 5246 sec 7.4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2) or the slightly more verbose version in [rfc 8446 sec 4.4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-4.4.2).

As Z.T. mostly-correctly commented, `-verify` is the **default** for `s_client` (you don't need to specify it) and if you don't specify `-CAfile` and/or `-CApath` by default (except for bugs in some obsolete versions) it uses a **default truststore**, configured at compile time, which can include either a single file with concatenated PEM certs or a directory containing separate PEM files with names or links using truncated subject hashes usually created by `c_rehash` **(add)** or, as commented, manually determined with `x509 -hash`; see the man page for verify(1ssl) on your system or [on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/verify.html). OpenSSL itself doesn't *provide* the root certs that go in such a truststore; *if* you are using a distro or other packaged version, the builder **usually** configures OpenSSL to use a set of root certs **provided by the distro or package**. (On distros I know, this distro-provided truststore is also used for *other* software including NSS, GNUtls, and Java; see below.) If you (or someone) built OpenSSL by hand, you have to do this yourself. Since you are not getting a verify error on public servers, your build presumably is using a truststore that has (at least some) public CA's preinstalled; you can see where this is with `openssl version -d` (plus the hardcoded names `cert.pem` and/or `certs`).

You can add your root or other anchor (see below) to this default truststore, or use `-CAfile` and/or `-CApath` to specify a custom one containing your own root(s) or anchor(s). On the distros I know, and probably others, you should NOT hand-modify the default files because they are automatically generated by a process that *also* sets the truststores used by other software such as NSS, GNUtls, and Java; these need to contain the same data (certs) but in different formats. Instead see e.g. `man update-ca-trust` for RedHat family or `man update-ca-certificates` for Debian family.

OpenSSL will use an intermediate (aka chain) cert or certs in the truststore to *build* the cert chain if needed, i.e. if not sent by the server (in violation of the RFC, but many do that), but historically it will only *accept* a chain -- either fully received from the server *or* (partly) built from the local truststore -- if it ends at a *root* that is in the local truststore. For recent versions, namely 1.0.2 up but only documented since 1.1.0, there is an option `-partial_chain` which does accept a chain ending in an intermediate (non-root) that is in the local truststore.

Comment: Thanks!  I've figured out part of my confusion.  Although my version of OpenSSL does not include a default truststore, at some point last year I must have done something that caused it to get copies of a large number of root-level certificates.  They were all stored in /var/ssl/certs, but that directory does not exist by default on AIX.  I renamed the directory and the openssl command then behaved consistently for anything I connected to--"verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate".  Now I just need to figure out why it considers my certificate chain to be self-signed.

Comment: It considers your root cert to be self-signed because it _is_; that's the _definition_ of a root cert. If you configure the server to not send the root cert `s_client` will report verify error 20 instead of verify error 19, if you think that is somehow significant, but in either case the cert cannot be verified. What matters about a root is not that it is self-signed, which it always is, but whether it is trusted.

Comment: I am aware that all root certificates are self-signed.  I was just trying to figure out why s_client was complaining about mine and no one else's.  After I discovered that a truststore actually existed on my system, I added my root certificate to it, used x509 -hash to get the hash value, created a symbolic link from the hash value to my root certificate, and s_client stopped complaining.  Now I fully understand s_client's criteria for determining if a root certificate is to be trusted.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: As I said, the difference is that if the server sends a chain including the root, and the root is not trusted, it gives error 19. If the server sends a chain _excluding_ the root, and the root is not trusted, it gives error 20. That difference is not in the cert, but in the server. If the root _is_ in the truststore -- and being in the default dir with a hash name is _one_ way, another is to put it in the default _file_ -- verification succeeds, whether or not the server sends it.

Comment: Right.  I understood that part after you initially explained it.  I just didn't realize that I had a truststore in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the fullchain I generated mine for use with Apache2 using:

`cat intermediateCA.crt rootCA.crt > fullchain.crt`

Without testing your exact circumstances I cannot suggest more than the order the web server is reading the certificate chain.

For OpenSSL stating your rootCA being self-signed. This could be due to your rootCA not being installed into your certificate store on the OS (or even web browser). Installing a `.crt` file across operating systems can vary, [Adding trusted root certificates to the server](https://manuals.gfi.com/en/kerio/connect/content/server-configuration/ssl-certificates/adding-trusted-root-certificates-to-the-server-1605.html) will explain how. Bear in mind that Mozilla Firefox uses its own certificate store.

When I first started being my own certificate authority, for similar purposes, I began issuing my own rootCA using a tutorial by [Jaime Linux](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/introduction.html) which may be more appropriate given you are issuing for a lab server, as the tutorial explains creating a flat database to track signed certificates.